# In VSCode, pygame has no 'init' member, tried adding code to settings.json, still having difficulties

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pygame

I am trying to create a hangman game using python in VScode. I imported pygame and now it won't let me do pygame.init(). I looked at other posts here and I tried it but I'm not sure why it is not working. Other posts said to go to setting.json and add

```
{ "python.linting.pylintArgs": [
    "--extension-pkg-whitelist=lxml"  // The extension is "lxml" not "1xml"
]
}

{"python.linting.pylintArgs": [
    "--unsafe-load-any-extension=y"
]
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RAvTN.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jc8Ps.png)

Comment: Please include code and outputs as text rather than images

Comment: Because `--extension-pkg-whitelist=lxml` whitelists the lxml module, not pygame. Use `--extension-pkg-whitelist=pygame` instead.

Comment: @molly -How are things going? Please let us know if there is any progress.

Answer (score 1):

1. If you want to turn off Pylint notifications via settings, please use the following format:

> ```
>  "python.linting.pylintArgs": 
>        [
>         "--extension-pkg-whitelist=lxml",  // The extension is "lxml" not "1xml"
>         "--unsafe-load-any-extension=y"
>       ],
> ```

[image]

In addition, using this method will turn off all Pylint information.

2.It is recommended that you use the following settings to turn off "[no-member](https://github.com/janjur/readable-pylint-messages/blob/master/README.md#e1101---s-r-has-no-r-members)" notifications after the code can be executed:

> ```
>  "python.linting.pylintArgs": [
>         "--disable=E1101"
>       ],
> ```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Vscode has launched new python language server `pylance` install it from extensions. After that change you language server to pylance.
You will get amazing features like autoimport, auto completion, linter,  debugger, etc.
Also check in which environment you have installed pygame. Switch the python interpreter using ctrl+shift+p.